# I just want the Mobile number range in php laravel which one I'm using posted below?

Tags: php, laravel

I just wanted to put a range any one can put a mobile number like `03005454342` any but not `0000000000000`

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: 'phone'=>'required|digits:11|digits_between:03000000000,03499999999', i want to use number limit 11 and the cell number limit started with 03

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp  This will allow you to add regex to validate inputs

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this (bootstrap-4):

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
   <div class="input-group-prepend">
       <span class="input-group-text" id="number">03</span>
   </div>
   <input type="number" maxlenght="9" min="0" max="999999999" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter number" aria-label="number">
</div>
```

with this simple code, you get second 9 numbers and first 2 number that can be set 03, sets on the backend and inserting into the database.